# firebase deploy fuctions error Upload Error: HTTP Error: 403

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-billing

firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'rouda-****'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> tsc

- functions: Finished running predeploy script.
  i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
  i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
  i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
- functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
- artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
- functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
  i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
  i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
  i  functions: packaged D:\IonicApps\RoudaApp\functions (59.1 KB) for uploading
  !  functions: Upload Error: HTTP Error: 403, `UserProjectAccountProblem`The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account.The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent

Error: HTTP Error: 403, `UserProjectAccountProblem`The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account.The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent

i tried firebase logout & login,
Pay as you go(plaze ) firebase project,
GC billing Account Enabled,
i changed the GC Billing Account for the project,
tried to deploy other firebase projects - same issue,
downgrade to firebase tools --version 11.1.0 & 11.14.3,
installed latest firebase-functions,
installed firebase-tools11.14.4,
could not deploy either..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error message is telling you there is a problem with your billing account. Specifically that it is in a disabled state. You will need to resolve it in the billing console: https://console.cloud.google.com/billing

Comment: I could not find any problems in my billing account , with contact to GC support they reply with suspend in the backend

Comment: I tried to change the billing account , changed firebase project still the error exist